# how to convert .net core console app into Window Service?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, service, console-application

I need to convert .net core console app into window service and send an email to the list of user from database at 6 om everyday.
I am using appsettings.json file from previous project of .net core but now I dont know how to merge it to app.config file. That's why I repeatedly getting an error :  `{"The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\appsettings.json'.":null}`

Comment: Don't post code with private API keys, you probably don't want to give the whole world access to that.

Comment: Please change your API key. Even when edited, some (trusted) users can still see the history.

Comment: Just a thougt: why a Windows service? You could set up a scheduled Windows task to be exceuted once, instead of a permanantly running service

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're fighting with the wrong enemy here. From the error text I can understand that Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns to you system32 path ("C:\WINDOWS\system32\).

Either this directory should contain your desired apsettings.json or you should change the base path.

There is no need to "merge it with app.config" as far as I understand

Also you should probably delete your ApiKey from this question

Comment: Please can anybody help me delete thsi qustion fully?

Comment: @AnirudhRawat https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300117/how-do-i-close-or-delete-a-question-that-i-have-asked